# Crash - UITableViewCell subclass KVO'ing UITableView.panGestureRecogonizer.state

Tags: ios, key-value-observing

**Situation:**

I've subclassed UITableViewCell because I need to add custom action buttons on either side of the UITableViewCell. There are certain situations where I need to set the UITableView back to normal (hide the custom action buttons). **e.g.** When the user scrolls upwards in the UITableView. To do this I am adding my custom UITableViewCell as an observer of the containing UITableView's UIPangestureRecognizer's state.

**Problem:**

When popping the UIViewController that contains the UITableView and custom UITableViewCells I receive the following error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'An instance 0x7b21b920 of
>   class UIScrollViewPanGestureRecognizer was deallocated while key value
>   observers were still registered with it. Current observation info:
>    (  Context: 0xb83618, Property: 0x7b3e13b0>
>    Context: 0xb83618,
>   Property: 0x7b3e13b0> 
>   Context: 0xb83618, Property: 0x7b3e13b0>  Context: 0xb83618, Property: 0x7b3e13b0> )'

Which is obviously saying that the UIPanGestureRecognizer is being deallocated before the custom UITableViewCell's are.

**Question:**

Where should I remove the custom UITableViewCell as an observer of the UITableView's UIPanGestureRecognizer so I don't encounter this exception?

**Code:** *(I hope this isn't too much code to comb through. I apologize if it is.)*

**CustomUITableViewCell.m**

```
#pragma mark - Setter Methods

- (void)setContainingTableView:(UITableView *)containingTableView
{
    if (self.isObservingContainingTableViewPanGestureRecognizer)
    {
        self.observingContainingTableViewPanGestureRecognizer = NO;

        [_containingTableView.panGestureRecognizer removeObserver:self forKeyPath:kUITableViewPanGestureRecognizerStateKeyPath];
    }

    _containingTableView = containingTableView;

    if (containingTableView)
    {
        self.observingContainingTableViewPanGestureRecognizer = YES;

        [containingTableView.panGestureRecognizer addObserver:self forKeyPath:kUITableViewPanGestureRecognizerStateKeyPath options:0 context:UITableViewPanGestureRecogonizerContext];
    }
}

#pragma mark -


#pragma mark - Overrides

- (void)didMoveToSuperview
{
    [super didMoveToSuperview];

    self.containingTableView = nil;

    UIView * view = self.superview;

    while (view)
    {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITableView class]])
        {
            self.containingTableView = (UITableView *)view;
            break;
        }

        view = view.superview;
    }
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    self.containingTableView = nil;
}

#pragma mark -

#pragma mark - Key Value Observing

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if (context == UITableViewPanGestureRecogonizerContext)
    {
        if ([keyPath isEqual:kUITableViewPanGestureRecognizerStateKeyPath])
        {
            UIPanGestureRecognizer * panGestureRecognizer = (UIPanGestureRecognizer *)object;

            if (panGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
            {
                CGPoint velocity = [panGestureRecognizer velocityInView:self.contentCellView];

                if (fabs(velocity.y) >= fabs(velocity.x))
                {
                    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object change:change context:context];
    }
}

#pragma mark -
```

As always, any help is greatly appreciated! Also, if anyone needs any more information please let me know.

**EDIT:**

Oddly enough, the custom UITableViewCell's dealloc method is called and the custom UITableViewCell is removed as an observer before I the exception is thrown.

Comment: in prepareForReuse ??

Comment: @HMHero, I receive the same exception if I remove the custom UITableViewCell as an observer in prepareForReuse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I needed to keep a reference to the UITableView's UIPanGestureRecognizer. More than likely I'll end up subclassing UITableView to eliminate some of the complications.

Answer (score 0):

UITableView is subclass of UIScrollView. If you only want to detect when user is scrolling it you can use scrollview delegate method:

> - (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;

Comment: This would require me to subclass UITableView though, which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: No need to subclass tableview. Just implement that method in controller which is delegate for your tableview.

Comment: Ah, that's a good idea but, I'd like to keep this logic contained in the custom UITableViewCell subclass.

Comment: Add dealloc method in UITableView cell and remove it as observer?
Remember not to call super in dealloc obviously :)

Comment: That's what I'm doing. It doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: you are doing this:
- (void)dealloc
{
    self.containingTableView = nil;
}

I am asking you to do this:
- (void)dealloc
{
    [containingTableView.panGestureRecognizer removeObserver:self forKeyPath:kUITableViewPanGestureRecognizerStateKeyPath context:UITableViewPanGestureRecogonizerContext];
}

Comment: If you look at the containingTableView setter method I remove the custom UITableViewCell as an observer. So, by setting self.containingTableView = nil the custom UITableViewCell will be removed as an observer. I do this because it is best practice to keep the add/remove calls in the setter method of the object you want to observe. But, just in case, I went ahead and did what you mentioned and it didn't work.

Comment: what did you try in dealloc? can you please copy paste your dealloc method? I hope you are not doing this: self.containingTableView = nil in dealloc. Also its not good practice to have UITablewView reference with UITableviewCell.

Comment: I put this inside of the dealloc method:`[self.containingTableView.panGestureRecognizer removeObserver:self forKeyPath:kUITableViewPanGestureRecognizerStateKeyPath];`

Comment: Can you do these steps:
1. Clean your setContainingTableView method. Don't remove observer there. 
2. In dealloc method just remove observer nothing else.
3. Remove didMoveToSuperview and in cellForRowIndexPath just assign cell.containingTableView = YourUITableView

Answer (score 0):

I think you should pass weak reference of table view to cell (as delegate) in cellForRowAtIndexPath rather than looking for the tableview in didMoveToSuperview. Overall, I don't think it's a good idea to have table view's gesture observer in cell. However if you really want it, make sure you register/unregister properly.
Also make sure isObservingContainingTableViewPanGestureRecognizer flag's initial value is right when the cell gets reused.